# Postgres Error for table

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I want to create this table, but i can’t,

Look this error.

```
CREATE TABLE ATTR(

    window character varying(64) NOT NULL

);
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "window"
>   LINE 2:     window character varying(64) NOT NULL

Answer (score 2):

`window` is a reserved word. You *can* create a column with that name if you enclose it in double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE ATTR
(
  "window" character varying(64) NOT NULL
);
```

More details about identifiers, quoted identifiers and keywords can be found in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

---

But I ***highly*** recommend you find a different name that does not need to be quoted. Using quoted identifiers is more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: I found this handy reserved word checker which checks in most of the major DBMSes: http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/?word=window

Comment: @Colin'tHart: the checker is quite outdated I'd say. `window` is a reserved word in SQL:2003 but the checker only checks the pretty old SQL:99 I'm also sure it's a reserved in Oracle. And SQL Server 2000 is also very much outdated. I would assume that since SQL Server also supports window functions it is a reserved word in any recent SQL Server version as well.